# Error when generating unit test on Activiti

Tags: eclipse, business-process-management, activiti

When I'm trying to do activiti BPM when i'm running "Generate a unit test" i'm getting error in Java file that created when running unit test 
[image]

i'm using eclipse juno and fedora OS

Comment: do you have jUnit library on your classpath?

Comment: ATMTA: no junit library in classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add junit library to your project.
properties->java build path->libraries->add libary